# Scikit-build pure Python package

Tags: python, cmake, pip

I want to create my own Python package that should be pip installable with `pip install .` from the directory containg setup.py. I also want to use scikit-build and CMake to have this code compatible with possible future modifications to make it run with Cython.

The test example is as follow:

```
Directory structure
.
|_lib
|    |_skbuild_test_lib
|    |                 |_ CMakeLists.txt
|    |                 |_ __init__.py
|    |                 |_ lib.py
|    |_ CMakeLists.txt
|    |_ __init__.py
|    |_ skbuild_test.py
|_ CMakeLists.txt
|_ main.py
|_ setup.py
```

The `__init__.py` files are all empty and the other files are as follows:

setup.py:

```
from skbuild import setup

setup(
    name='skbuild_test',
    version='0.0.1',
    packages=['lib', 'lib.skbuild_test_lib'],
)
```

main.py:

```
import skbuild_test

skbuild_test.hello_world()
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(skbuild_test VERSION 0.1.0)

add_subdirectory (lib)
```

lib/CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_subdirectory (skbuild_test_lib)

install (FILES __init__.py DESTINATION skbuild_test)
install (FILES skbuild_test.py DESTINATION skbuild_test)
```

lib/skbuild_test.py:

```
import lib

def hello_world():
    print(lib.foo())
```

lib/skbuild_test/CMakeLists.py:

```
install (FILES __init__.py DESTINATION skbuild_test)
install (FILES lib.py DESTINATION skbuild_test)
```

lib/skbuild_test/lib.py:

```
def foo():
    return 'Hello World!'
```

A repository with this exact structure can be found [here](https://github.com/FMalerba/skbuild_test).

What I am trying to achieve is for setup.py to install everything inside the lib folder and then have the main.py file able to run.
The code as is when I run `python setup.py install` throws (on my Windows 10 system) the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 6, in <module>
    packages=['lib', 'lib.skbuild_test_lib'],
  File "venv\lib\site-packages\skbuild\setuptools_wrap.py", line 625, in setup
    cmake_source_dir, skbuild_kw['cmake_install_dir'])
  File "venv\lib\site-packages\skbuild\setuptools_wrap.py", line 757, in _classify_installed_files
    install_root, to_platform_path(path)))
skbuild.exceptions.SKBuildError:
  CMake-installed files must be within the project root.
    Project Root  : skbuild_test\_skbuild\win-amd64-3.7\cmake-install
    Violating File: skbuild_test\_skbuild\win-amd64-3.7\cmake-install\skbuild_test\__init__.py
```

Note that if I instead run the command `pip install .` I get no error, however the package is installed incorrectly and main.py will throw an error.

Comment: Please include your code within the question, not in external website, you will most likely edit your git repo in future and the data for this question will be lost or very hard to find. It is also way better for people who want to help you if they see the code directly, which increases the chances your question will be answered.

Comment: @Ruli Thank you for the heads-up, I will change this asap

Answer (score 1):

I think I managed to find a way to have this work. To see how my `CMakeLists.txt`s are, you can look at the already referenced repo in the `solution` [branch](https://github.com/FMalerba/skbuild_test/tree/solution)

Answer (score -1):

First, I think you're over-complicating things, ie, you don't have anything for cmake to build, so why are you using scikit-build in the first place?

Second, I've been "testing" using cmake/scikit-build/other lately, and make no claims to being an expert with either, BUT I think you're barking up the wrong tree with your setup.py goals.  What I mean be that is, it's not the job for setup.py, rather you should probably use cmake for that (although I'm not sure I see the point either way).  Both setup.py and cmake have their own ideas about install, and would lean towards a cmake install command after building (something).

If you want to see a real-world example using a cython extension, you can look here: https://github.com/freepn/py-re2/tree/skbuild

Comment: So the reason I want to use cmake is because I want to later add (or convert to) cython and I would like the install process to be compatible. Furthermore, I want to use `setup.py` and scikit-build because I want to be able to call `pip install .` from the folder and have the package installed in python's site-packages.
To see an example where the thing I am looking for is achieved go [here](https://github.com/deepmind/hanabi-learning-environment). In this repo they actually have a mix of python and C code, but nonetheless the python files are installed via cmake as called by `setup.py`